Minimum SDP for receiving SRTP stream
Inspired by this question : Minimum SDP for making a H264 RTP stream?
I have made applications that sends H.264 video data from Android to Windows using RTP. I want to add encryption on my features.
Is there an example of a SDP for setting up Secure RTP video stream?
Current implementation uses minimal SDP for receiving normal RTP stream. I'm using SDP files based on the link above;
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
m=video 5004 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000

I am trying to add SRTP options to this SDP file, but I couldn't find good example.

You should read the RFC for srtp
